# How to enable GZIP Compression on BigCommerce site

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, bigcommerce

For anybody familiar with `BigCommerce`, I'm sure you already know whether `GZIP` compression is possible to configure or not on the platform. I minified my `JS` files and instead of them pointing to the `CDN`, they're looking straight to the local files because this is the only way it will update the files.

Now I want to enable `GZIP` for these files but I can't find where to do it(if it's even possible).

Thank you for anybody who takes the time to offer an answer!

Comment: Hi - it is not possible to enable gzip compression since you do not have access to configure the web server. That said, another step you could take instead is to combine your CSS and JS files into as few as possible, with the goal of reducing the number of web requests needed to load your site. Be warned, doing this might introduce its own challenges in regards to maintaining the combined files, file pointing/reference issues, and potential conflicts in code (more so applicable to combining JS files). Try reducing your image file sizes too. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, you actually do not have access to the `.htaccess` file in BigCommerce. This is because BigCommerce does not run on Apache, but it actually runs on Nginx.

Not only that but `.htaccess` can produce security risks, which obviously is something you want to avoid using BigCommerce.

You can however add the following code to the top of all of your pages to compress PHP:

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't see an htacess file anywhere in BigCommerce. If I use WebDav, not all the files download so I have to use all the files I have on the front end management system. Is there a way to navigate to the htaccess file?

Comment: Actually my apologies - after some further research there is actually no .htaccess file available in BigCommerce. This is due to security threats and the fact that it runs on Ngix, not Apache. I've edited my answer.

Comment: All of the pages are .html, and I'm not able to rename them to .php

Comment: Because BigCommerce is SaaS, you can't make PHP related changes. However, this is enabled automatically if the BigCommerce CDN is used.